# Deploying Container Image in Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS ) using AzureDevops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-aks

I have configured an Azure Kubernetes Service.
I have completed a couple of deployments successfully using Kubectl task in Azure DevOps. The task command is "kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml".

In the deployment.yaml I have some items which I would like to configure as a variable for example image as below

```
containers:
- name: xxxxx
  image: containerregistry.azurecr.io/xxxxx:5517
  ports:
  - containerPort: 80.
```

Now I am publishing the docker image with building number being 5517,5518 and so on. So how can I change the image tag on the fly when "kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml" is executed. The deployment. Yaml is checked into my Azure DevOps repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have 2 options:

1. preprocess the file and replace tokens (there is a task for that)
2. use [helm](https://helm.sh/)

You obviously have other options like using pulumi\terraform\flux\etc, but these are the most straight forward ones to use from your starting point

Comment: Cool thanks a lot. Just figured out to load the content using PS and replacing on the fly and then getting the modified file.

Comment: helm is probably a better approach. you have `bake` command on azure devops kube task.

Comment: yes, for first iteration i am using kubectl apply later I will use helm as tiller also needs to be installed before helm can be used. Thanks Thomas

Comment: Is there a way in Azure pipelines where i can obtain release artifact source for example a variable that will give me Azure container registry name?

Comment: start a new question, please

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Just as a sidenote, in the current helm versions (3+) there is no longer a tiller component. This was only necessary in helm 2 and was removed because it was no longer necessary because of changes in how Kubernetes works.

Comment: has nothing to do with how kubernetes work, they redid helm model, not kubernetes